# MotionEvent - How to do action on tap, not drag

Tags: android, listview, touch, listitem, motionevent

I have been searching online and on StackOverflow for how to do an action in an `onTouchListener` if the event was a tap, not a motion of any kind, but I haven't been able to find an answer and what I have tried doesn't work either. I have a `ListView` `Adapter` and in the `getView` method, I have set the `onTouchListener` on the `listItem`.

**What I want to do is when the `listItem` is tapped, I want to display a `Toast`, but if the event was a drag (*like the user scrolling through the list)*, I don't want to display the `Toast`.**

Below is the code that I have tried. (*`makeToast` is a function for making a `Toast` and `events.getRelation()` is the String I want to have in the `Toast`.*):

```
listItem.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_ENTER) {
            makeToast(events.getRelation());
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            //  makeToast(events.getRelation());
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL) {
            //   makeToast(events.getRelation());
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            // makeToast(events.getRelation());
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.AXIS_SCROLL) {
            //   makeToast(events.getRelation());
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.AXIS_VSCROLL) {
            //    makeToast(events.getRelation());
        } else {
            //makeToast(events.getRelation());
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

I have tried having the `makeToast` method under different types of `MotionEvents`, but I still don't get the results I want because either a `Toast` is not made at all, or it is made when I am scrolling, not tapping. Would anyone be able to help me with this? I feel like it is a simple problem, but I have been unable to find a solution

Comment: That question had to do with implementing `onTouch` and `onClick` because `onClick` is never called after `onTouch`. My question is differentiating between a scroll and a tap to create the `Toast` on the tap.

Comment: I agree that the other user's *reason* for wanting to be able to detect a tap/ a click in `onTouch()` is different from yours. But since both of you want to *achieve* the same thing, please explain why the answers to the other post are not helpful in your case. (IMO the accepted self-answer is not really good but there is more than one other answer explaining how to evaluate the time between DOWN and UP in order to make a decision)

Comment: Thanks 0X0nosugar. The second answer from that post helped me. I was not able to find an answer before you posted that so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To detect Single and Double Tap in android use the following methods

**`class GestureTap extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener { @Override public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) { Log.i("onDoubleTap :", "" + e.getAction()); return true; } @Override public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) { Log.i("onSingleTap :", "" + e.getAction()); return true; } }`**

And add the following code in onTouch listener

**`@Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) { new GestureDetector(this, new GestureTap()).onTouchEvent(event); return true; }`**

Answer (score -1):

According to what I understand, I think you wish to set Click listener to the whole activity!
To do this, add [`ViewTreeObserver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver):

```
ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = myView.getViewTreeObserver();
viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    //make Toast
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18000128/9819031

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. I know how to make a `Toast`. What I am having difficulty with is detecting whether a touch was a tap or a motion and then making a `Toast` if it was a tap. The problem is with detecting a touch vs motion.

Comment: ok i will see for this

Comment: See edited answer!

Comment: Thanks for trying Gourav, but I don't want to set a `ClickListener` to the whole activity because each individual row in the `ListView` makes a `Toast` of a different message. Also, my question is about detecting different types of `MotionEvents` like taps or drags, not making `Toasts` or `ClickListeners`.

Comment: Tell me one thing, do you have listview in your activity?

Comment: Yes I have a Listview. That is why, as I said in the question, I'm implementing the `getView` method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186014/discussion-between-gourav-and-ishaan-javali).